# Intersection of 2 lines in 3D if i know they are on the same plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

How can i find the intersection point of 2 lines in 3D, if i know that they lie on the same plane.

I have found some more general ways to solve this in 3D but i thought that maybe there are some simple way to calculate intersection point if it is know that the lines are on the same plane.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two lines in $\mathbb{R^3}$ intersect, **always they lie on a common plane**, so there is nothing special in this condition and thus no shortcut exists to solve.